# SharePoint calculated column using "Created" results in 12/30/99?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am looking for a formatted date field using Created. So I created a calculated column titled Added with the following formula: `=TEXT(Created,"m/d/yy")`. Data type is `Date and Time`.  Date and Time Format: `Date Only`.

I added the column and all existing entries for this list have the new column working properly.  However, when a brand new item is added my calculated column displays 12/30/99. If If I view a list column and save it all items in the list are updated and the column is properly displayed.

Is there another approach or a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, newly added items to the list worked fine. It was when I modified an item that the date erroneously fell back to 12/30/99. The fix was wrapping `Created` in brackets `[Created]`. I'm still curious as to what exactly was happening if anyone cares to debug or offer an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, the addition of the brackets around the Created field corrected this issue for me as well (in SharePoint 2013 on premises). Can't comment why this is the case but it works. I was initally afraid that the Created date was not available yet at the time of the item's creation and there would be no work around but this appears to have fixed the calculation.